# Trying to pip install ibm-db in a virtual env on IBM i resulting in error limits.h

Tags: python, pip, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to install ibm-db into a virtual environment with Python running on an IBM i.  I'm running into the following exception about limits.h no such file or directory.  All the other similar questions I've found were either on Linux or MacOS, so not sure how to resolve this on an IBM i.

[image]

I also tried doing this at the system level without a virtual environment and ran into the same problem.  I'm trying to install ibm-db version 3.0.2 (latest at time of this question) and that could be part of the problem.  If I list the system installed packages, there is a version 2.0.5.12 of ibm-db already installed.

My IBM i is at release V7R2.

[image]

**Update 2021-01-15 @ 1:42PM**

This seems to not be limited to the latest version of ibm-db.  I tried installing a few other versions, right down to 2.0.5 and I get the same error.  So it sounds like something is missing in the environment.

Comment: I noticed you also posted this as a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/issues/592).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite a few mentions of IBM i (or i5) in the [main ibm-db project](https://pypi.org/project/ibm-db/), it really doesn't have proper support for being run *from* IBM i. (It may be the case that connecting *to* IBM i from some other platform still works; I have not verified this.) If you want to use ibm-db with IBM's Python for PASE, you need to be using [Kevin Adler's fork](https://github.com/kadler/python-ibmdb). See the [issue](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/issues/389) establishing this.

The most straightforward way to do this is via the RPMs (installed via yum directly, or the Access Client Solutions GUI). It looks like you already have the latest version of this installed (2.0.5.12 as of this writing).

Further, if you want to use virtual environments (which is a good idea), your best bet is to use the `--system-site-packages` option, so that it finds the RPM-installed one.

Finally, if you are not tied to ibm-db, the recommended way to connect in a [PEP-249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)-ish way is through ODBC. There is now sufficient support for ODBC on PASE that you can actually develop and test code connecting from your PC to IBM i using [pyodbc](https://pypi.org/project/pyodbc/), and then just use that exact same code on PASE.

Comment: I have the ODBC driver installed in my IBM i and was able to run some tests using isql.  I created a new Python virtual environment and attempted to install pyodbc, but I run into the same error about limits.h no such file or directory.  Beyond that, you mention the ODBC connection is the recommended approach.  Is there better performance from the ODBC connection?

Comment: I was able to get ODBC working with pyodbc on my IBM i.  I discovered that IBM has an RPM for python3-pyodbc 4.0.27-0 available through yum.  After installing that, I was able to use pyodbc in my Python script.  So my only question now is, does the ODBC approach provide better performance than the ibm-db approach?

Comment: The performance is similar. Depending on what you microbenchmark, ibm-db is sometimes faster, pyodbc is sometimes faster. In any event, the difference is not big enough that you will notice it without very careful timing. The reason ODBC is recommended is that it is available for free on PASE as well as the major mainstream platforms. To use ibm-db on your Linux or Windows machine, you would need the extremely expensive IBM Db2 Connect product, which most places don't already have.

Comment: Yes definitely the biggest gain with ODBC is being able to develop from my laptop and connect to the IBM i over ODBC.  I use WSL and VS Code, so having the Linux driver installed locally makes for a nice development experience.  Thanks for all your help John.